# MacBook Air Yosemite not loading apps

Tags: macos, command-line, applications

I am new to Mac but am a steady Linux and Windows user. My friend gave me an old MacBook Air 2012 to look at and as far as I know, it looks bad. Maybe somebody will have an idea.

http://lneletro.us/macerror is my website with two gif files in this directory. They are about 20 MB in size so don't bother trying to load the files in the browser just download them, let me know if you have any problems.

The first gif depicts the apps bouncing in the taskbar upon clicking on them, and the second depicts trying to load the app from Terminal and the error when loading Mail.app. iTunes throws error 13014 after launching from the taskbar, after looking the error up it appears to be a corrupted file error or something. I ran `diskutil verifyVolume` in Terminal and it appears that the drive isn't corrupted.

I am able to move the mouse on the screen but when I try clicking various options on the top toolbar the screen freezes and it's like the os reloads the desktop. Spotlight searches the app but won't load any. Another random but weird fact is that QuickBooks is installed and it launches to the menu that asks for a company file but on clicking the company file, it throws an error.

I'll be happy to elaborate on request thanks for input.

Comment: You probably should upgrade to the latest version of macOS that is compatible. This would be macOS 10.15 (Catalina). Since you are having issues, a clean install would be best. One possible upgrade path would be Yosemite to El Capitan to High Sierra and finally Catalina.

Comment: It sounds to me like the hard drive may be faulty, especially if it’s the original spinning disk that came with it. In that model it’s straightforward to replace it with an SSD, then you can do a clean install of Catalina as David suggested.

Comment: @jasonology do for sure all 2012 era models contain a hdd or did they ship with ssds

Comment: You might want to find your exact model https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201608 then look up what can be done on http://www.everymac.com

Comment: The 2012 MacBook Air models do not have HDD.